# how to validate SWT textbox to allow '*' character in it?

Tags: java, swt

I am trying to validate SWT textbox to accept only alphanumerics, '`.`' and '`*`' characters, so the user will be able to enter wildcard patterns (e.g.- `*.txt`).

With the below code I am not able to input a '`*`' character(with the `*` button in num pad of keyboard also). Please help.

```
text.addVerifyListener(new VerifyListener() {
    @Override
    public void verifyText(VerifyEvent e) {
        e.doit=Character.isLetterOrDigit(e.character)
            ||e.keyCode=='.'
            ||e.keyCode=='*'
            ||e.keyCode==SWT.ARROW_LEFT
            ||e.keyCode==SWT.ARROW_RIGHT
            ||e.keyCode==SWT.BS;

    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are testing the `keyCode` field against a character - the key code value is often not the same as a character value. So use:

```
|| e.character == '.'
|| e.character == '*'
```

or if you want to only allow the keypad . * use:

```
|| e.keyCode == SWT.KEYPAD_DECIMAL
|| e.keyCode == SWT.KEYPAD_MULTIPLY
```

Answer (score 0):

private void validateCharacaterspecials() {

```
    this.JText.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            char keyChar = e.getKeyChar();

            char c = e.getKeyChar();

            system.out.println(e.getKeyChar());

            if ("+/*-][|ª·$%&/()=?]'[!\"¿".contains(String.valueOf(c))) {
                getToolkit().beep();
                system.out.println("delete");
                e.consume();
            }

            if (Character.isLowerCase(keyChar)) {
                e.setKeyChar(Character.toUpperCase(keyChar));
            }

        }
    });

}
```